Using Flyway with MongoDB and Spring Boot
I'm trying to use Flyway with MongoDB and Spring Boot. In other projects, I've successfully used Flyway with SQL DBs, and Spring automatically runs the migrations. With MongoDB, however, it seems that the that Spring Boot autoconfiguration isn't initializing the FlywayMigrationInitializer as it normally does.
I followed Redgate's documentation to add the dependencies to my pom.xml: https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/supported-databases/mongodb.
And for the Spring Boot part, I've tried to piece together examples from these Github issues:

https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3944
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3856

Here's my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mongo-app</name>
    <description>mongo-app</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <flyway.version>10.21.0</flyway.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>${flyway.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-database-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${flyway.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.github.kornilova203</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongo-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kornilova203</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/mongo-jdbc-standalone-1.19.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Here's my application.yml:
spring:
  application:
    name: mongo-app
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017
      database: example
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/example
    driver-class-name: com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver
  flyway:
    url: jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/example
    driver-class-name: com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver
    environment: "mongodb"
    fail-on-missing-locations: true
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    sqlMigrationSuffixes:
      - ".js"
    enabled: true

What am I missing to get Flyway migrations to run automatically?
Full source code for the app can be found here: https://github.com/cfinlinson-incomm/mongodb-app.

Dependencies with scope system aren't included in the final jar (this is default behavior for Maven). So at runtime the MongoJdbcDriver isn't available.

See also https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/maven-plugin/packaging.html#packaging.repackage-goal.parameter-details.include-system-scope on how to enable/include it.

Thanks for bringing this up. I got everything to work locally when running the app in IntelliJ, but it failed when I deployed it to a test environment. This was the last trick I needed!

I got this working by making some additional changes to my pom.xml.
First, the FlywayConfiguration class only gets activated by Spring Boot if JdbcUtils is in the classpath. To resolve that, I added this dependency to my pom.xml:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

Second, as M. Deinum explained in a comment, dependencies with scope system are not included in the final jar, so while this worked for me when running locally via IntelliJ, it failed when I deployed it to a test environment. To resolve that, I modified the spring-boot-maven-plugin like so:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
  </configuration>
</plugin>


Hello, i would add that you may consider pulling the mongo jdbc driver from maven instead of using system dependencies
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.dbvis/mongo-jdbc-standalone/1.19
by doing that you would not depend on local jar asset on a build chain (ci/cd, etc)
